# How to filter an array and return new array of objects with indexed values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given the array `const vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];`

How can I filter and return a new array of indexed key/value pair objects for example:

```js
const vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// My fail attempt using filter()
let obj = vals.filter((n, i) => {
  return new Object({ i: n % 2 });
});
return obj;

// expected result [{1:2}, {3:4}, {5:6}, {7:8}]
```

I need to keep the index values as I will filter 2 different arrays with different criteria and associated them later.

**Update**
Second attempt using `map()` as suggested in the comments

```js
let obj = vals.map((n, i) => {
  if (n % 2) {
    return { [i]: n };
  }
});
```

Gives me the following:
`[{0:1}, undefined, {2:3}, undefined, {4:5}, undefined, {6:7}, undefined, {8:9}]`

Comment: The `.filter()` method *only* does filtering, not filtering + mapping. I don't see the condition you want to filter by, you just seem to be doing a mapping but then expect to get less elements at the end.

Comment: Why do you think [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) would do what you think it does? The documentation is quite clear on its behavior.

Comment: `vals.map`, and `{ [i]: ... }`…?

Comment: Why `new Object({ ... })`? `i` is the index of the current element, but the first element in your "expected result" has `"1"` as its only property. Why? And with `n` being the actual element how is the first value `2` when `n === 1`?

Comment: @Andreas the array of objects I'm after should be `{ index : filtered_value }` hope that makes sense

Comment: @deceze Got your point, I'll try using a map instead, I'm new to this high order js functions

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. What's that `filtered_value` you're talking about?

Comment: @Andreas that will be `n%2` to get even numbers

Comment: For every even element in `vals` you want an object that stores the index of that element in `vals` as its only property and the element itself as the value of that property?

Comment: @Andreas that meet the condition correct

Comment: Is the order of the elements always uneven, even, uneven, even, ... or could the array contain even/uneven values only, or any order...?

Comment: @Andreas could be of any size

Comment: You need a simple `for` loop with an `if` condition: `const output = []; for(let i=0; i<vals.length; i++) if(vals[i] % 2 == 0) output.push({ [i]: vals[i] })`

Comment: @Andreas I almost got it using `let obj = vals.map((n, i) => { if (n % 2) return { [i]: n } });`

Comment: Why is this not in the question instead of that strange `.filter()` approach? That would have shown the actual intent/requirement and we would not have to ask a bunch of questions in the comments... Or if there would have been a proper requirement... -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas I understand, but I was using filter as I thought that was the correct approach at the time until @deceze hint me the `map()` option, I'll edit the post to avoid misleading others in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of `{ key: value }` objects where `key` is the index, and the values are only even without the odd values, you can do this:

```js
const vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
const result = vals.map((v, i) => [i, v])
                   .filter(([_, v]) => v % 2 == 0)
                   .map(([i, v]) => ({ [i]: v }));
                   
console.log(result);
```

With the first `map`, you make a list of `[[0, 1], ...]` pairs to save the index for later.
Then you filter your index-value pairs so only even values remain.
Then you pack those pairs into an object in another `map`.

This can be done more efficiently with a single iteration using `reduce`:

```js
const vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const result = vals.reduce((a, v, i) => {
    if (v % 2 == 0) {
        a.push({ [i]: v });
    }
    return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I have learnt a lot with this little exercise is all good I don't shy from my mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Youn can try simple `for` loop or the `reduce` function

```
let arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i<vals.length-1;i += 2)
{ 
    let obj={};
    obj[vals[i]]=vals[i+1]; 
    arr.push(obj); 
};
```